# OSX server 10.5 Permissions in POSIX, how to get to ACL?

Tags: mac-osx, access-control-list

I'm using an OSX 10.5 server and am having some permission issues using the current POSIX system. I want to switch to ACL, but I can't for the life of me figure out how this is done.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured this out. From the workgroup manager file sharing permission settings... You open up the groups and drag the group you want into the ACL section.

Then save settings and propagate down the line.